# Can I implement my own integer arithmetic and integer data types in C?

Tags: c, types

Data types are system depended in C and their bit lengths may change for different machines. I am aware of the < inttypes.h > header which provide fixed width integer datatypes. However, this header guarantee that provided data type has **at least** specified number N of bits. ([Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types))

But I need data types with exact bit lengths in my applications. For example, if data type is uint16_t it **should** be 16 bits, not **at least** 16 bits. Now my question is: Can i define new integer data types using "unsigned char" and "char" data types (Since they will be 8 bits in every machine) as main bulding blocks? Can I implement related arithmetic operations and overload arithmetic operators like "+"? Or are there other solutions already?

Edit: My exact problem is about implementations of cryptographic algorithms like DES which require fixed bits.

Comment: There already is an inttype which guarantees it's "at least" N bits.

Comment: C does not allow overloading - try C++. Anyway what is the exact problem you have encountered

Comment: `uint16_t` has **exactly** 16 bits.

Comment: "Exact-width integer (`intN_t`, `uintN_t`) types which _are guaranteed to have the same number N of bits across all implementations_. Included only if it is available in the implementation."

Comment: @Michael What does "if it is available in the implementation" mean? It  sounds crucial but not explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need types with exact number of bits, use types like `int24_t` or `uint16_t` - they are guaranteed to have exact number of bits. C provides types like `int_least8_t` separately, but what you need is `uint16_t` and you do not need to implement anything.

Comment: I just wonder: Is there *any* current platform that has a `int24_t` ?

Comment: But in wiki page it says for the exact width integer types "Included only if it is available in the implementation". How do we know these types are available? Are you really sure these types are machine independent and available for all cases?

Comment: Anyway, I tested sizeof() of all < stdint.h > intxx_t and uintxx_t data types. They returned exact byte values. So they seem reliable. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

you can do so by using bit-fields in structures. You can set the number of bit to a desired length.
example:-

```
    struct defineInt{
        int a:16;
    };
```

Comment: It is not very practical for arithmetic operations though

Comment: Yeah it is best useful with the bitwise operations.
but arithmatic operations depends on the types of all the operands in the operation, the result of an operation will always be promoted to a higher datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the c spec guarantees a char is 8 bits, nice idea though.

Comment: The POSIX specification requires that CHAR_BIT == 8, compare http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html. - But in any case, `uint16_t` has 16 bits, independent of CHAR_BIT.

Answer (score 1):

don't (re)use char. define your own type.

For Cxx11, have a look to [char16_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/char16_t) and family.
 - char is for 8-bit code units,
 - char16_t is for 16-bit code units, and
 - char32_t is for 32-bit code units.

Answer (score 0):

There already is an int type which guarantees it's "at least" N bits namely `int_leastNN_t` available in [stdint.h](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/stdint.html).

Also you can "roll your own" by declaring a typedef which aliases a particular int type based on either the current architecture or the `sizeof` the particular int size.